# Google Apps Script returns wrong timezone

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

My google Apps Script script returned a wrong timezone with `Date()`. What I expect is GMT+8 (because I live in Asia) but the script timezone returns GMT-5. Even the log time is not match.

Code:

```
let date = new Date(); 
Logger.log(date);
```

[image]
How can I change it from GMT-5 to GMT+8? Any help would be highly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Where's the code?

Comment: Did you know that your spreadsheet and script can have different timezones?

Comment: [mcve]..............

Comment: Yes I am aware, I have already checked the timezone of my spreadsheet file at spreadsheet settings. Even my google calendar, the timezone set is GMT+8(Taipei). Code: function date() { let = date = new Date(); Logger.log(date);}

Comment: What's the timezone of the script project

Comment: This is not correct `function date() { let = date = new Date(); Logger.log(date);} ` and the function posted in your question is not either.  It's not a [mcve]

Comment: The timezone of the script project is GMT-5 which is America base on the log output.

Comment: sorry wrong type function date() {let date = new Date(); Logger.log(date);}

Comment: Well I can tell you without even running it that it will work for me.  So how about shutting down your project and closing the spreadsheet and the browser and bringing it back up and trying it again. And if that doesn't work start  the script in a fresh spreadsheet

Comment: I have upload a new image, pleas have a look. Thank you

Comment: In the future you should be aware that we do not like images of the  [mcve] because then we can't copy the code and run it ourselves.  You will get down voted for that.

Comment: been doing it for 3 days. closing the browser, changing the timezone of the calendar and spreadsheet, deleting the project then creating a new one. Still not able to resolve the project.

Comment: So it's returning the timezone of the script what's wrong with that?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time posting a question in stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes it return a timezone that is not appropriate base on my location. I'm expecting it to return a timezone of GMT+8 which my location timezone

Comment: That's no excuse. I've posted plenty of questions and I know for a fact that they gave you several opportunities to read instructions to help you post a better question.

Comment: You said that the script project timezone is gmt-5.  It's in the 7th comment

Comment: Yes, it is GMT-5 and I want to change it to GMT+8

Comment: So change the timezone of the script. I don't know how to do it with the new editor so go back to the old editor and do it there.  It's in the file menu in project properties.

Comment: This situation might be related to this Google issue tracker. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72019223

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can change the *timezone* of your script by modifying the manifest file.

This can be done by going to **Project Settings** and ticking the **Show "appsscript.json" manifest file in editor**.

[image]

Afterwards, just update the manifest file to this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Taipei",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

#### Note

Please bear in mind that you can modify this and input the *timezone* of your choice.